# Win10 indexed content search doesn't do its job

Tags: windows-10, search

After doing all I could to avoid it, I moved from Win7 to Win10. I have a few thousands docs and pdfs (less than 50GB), and Windows search used to work within milliseconds. Not anymore. Although file content is fully indexed for all needed files (and not much beyonds it), it takes SEVERAL MINUTES *(sic!)* to get the results. Any idea about what I should do? I use this feature several dozens of times a day, and it ruins my work routine completely.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to disable Windows Search. This would also save on some computer resources.

As a replacement I suggest the free
[Everything by voidtools](https://www.voidtools.com/),
which is IMHO much better, and which will also do the search in milliseconds
and while you type.

Comment: Thanks, but in Everything's Q&A ,they declare that 'File content is not indexed, searching content is slow'. I mainly use this tool to search for content, e.g. to find the 23 Word files located in 17 different folders, in which a certain name appears.... Should I ignore their disclaimer?

Comment: Everything only does file names. For contents search I use [Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/?src=abt), although it doesn't use an index.